# Запустить активити из присоединённых контактов

Tags: java, android-sdk, android, activity

Вообщем есть контакт присоединённый к аккаунту, как мне при клике на этот аккаунт открыть активити? Например когда к контакту присоединён Webmoney при клике
[image: Контакт]

Comment: Я лично не могу понять ,что значит *контакт присоединен к аккаунту*

Comment: когда вы синхранизируете контакты из Google, он привязаны к какому-то аккаунту. можете посмотреть в Settings->Accounts->My accounts. У меня аналогично, только вместо гугла моё приложение у которого есть аккаунт Manager(см. скриншот)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В strings добавляем

```
<string name="mime_type">vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.profile</string>
```

В нужную activity добавляем

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:mimeType="@string/mime_type" />
        </intent-filter>
```

При добавлении контакта делаем ещё

```
String MIMETYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.profile";

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
            .build());
```